# Suppose 99 passengers are assigned to one of two flights. Show one of the flights has at least 50 passengers assigned to it.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am having problems tackling this Existential logic problem: (source: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jmh93/stfcs/STfCS2010.pdf, pg 15)

> Suppose 99 passengers are assigned to one of two flights, one to
>   Almeria and one to Barcelona. Show one of the flights has at least 50 passengers assigned to it. (Which flight is it?)

I do acknowlege, with the info given above, you could have 1 passenger going to Almeria, and the other 98 passengers going to Barcelona. You could have 1 passenger going to Barcelona, and the other 98 passengers going to Almeria.

So, is it possible to say:

∃A.∃B. ((L1(A)∩L2(B)) ∪ (L1(B)∩L2(A)) ===> (L3(A)∪ L3(B)) .

(There exists a flight to Almeria, and a flight to Barcelona such that, if, a: Almeria has at least 1 passenger in the flight, and Barcelona has at least 98 passengers in its flight; or, if b:, Barcelona has at least 1 passenger on one flight, and Almeria has at least 98 passengers on the other flight. Then, either Almeria or Barcelona have at least 50 passengers assigned to it)

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Answer (score 6):

Suppose, to the contrary that *both* flights had strictly less than $50$ passengers. (i.e. $F_1 \leq 49$ and $F_2 \leq 49$).

What can you say about $F_1 + F_2$?

Comment: I agree this is the correct answer. I think you may have been getting a bit bogged down in the notation and missed the idea -- to understand how proof by contradiction can be used to show existence.

Comment: @Nico Not really, I just wanted to state it rigorously. I could just have ended with the first sentence I suppose, but that would've been better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Deepak, thank you, I will need to review proof of contradiction!

Comment: @Deepak I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I was referring to the OP when I said that. I can see how that could easily be misconstrued, however. Your answer (or hint, I suppose) is both accurate and concise.

Comment: @Nico Thanks Nico, no worries. :)